# InDesign: how to import text from Word Perfect or Pages format

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, pdf, book

My book designer is using InDesign, but she cannot import text in Word Perfect or Pages (mac). She likes me to send my text in PDF but then she retypes it. It is causing lots of confusion and error.  I have a new Macbook Pro and am willing to learn or buy any program so that my designer can just import my text directly. It seems crazy that we cannot do this. BTW we are both 60+ yo ladies. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Pages converts to Word easily -- just save/export from Pages as Word format.

There are also several online converters to convert .pages to .doc or .docx.

**There's no excuse for retyping a provided text file... none.** That's just a recipe for errors.

Even if you sent it as a PDF, you can OCR and export a text file from a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Google account, try uploading your original text to [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/). Its most likely possible to then convert your file to a DOC/DOCX compatible version, which you can share online with your designer or download as a new file.